# page refresh after submitting with laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-4

I have built a contact page using laravel-4.2 allowing users to submit data. My contact page has a lot of information and the submitting form is at the bottom of the page. every time there is an error when submitting the form, the page refresh and i have to scroll down to the form to actually see the errors on the page.How to fix this. I guess i have to use ajax.
 here is my ContactController.php

```
<?php
class ContactController extends BaseController{

    public function getIndex (){

    return View::make('Contact.contact');
    }

    public function postContact(){

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'name'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'sujet'=>'required',
        'telephone'=>'required|numeric',
        'message'=>'required'
    ));

        if($validator->passes()){

            $contact = new Contact();

            $contact -> name = Input::get('name');
            $contact -> email = Input::get('email');
            $contact -> subject = Input::get('subject');
            $contact -> telephone = Input::get('telephone');
            $contact -> message = Input::get('message');

            $contact->save();

            return Redirect::route('contact')
                ->with('success','Message sent!');
        }else{

            return Redirect::route('contact')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `I guess i have to use ajax` - your answered your own question.

Comment: You can show the errors at the top of the form.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange i figured it. thanks

Comment: Would you mind sharing the answer... I'm stuck with the same issue...